# Instance Object not position correctly

Tags: rendering, instances

I was follow donut tutorial to make sprinkle on donut but the sprinkle position underneath the icing

timestamp 8:20 https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jNmnPXY9UQA&t=511s

[image]

[image]

X ray mode
[image]

And I have try a new mesh with same method and it has no problem. May I know what is the problem with my old mesh?
[image]

Comment: We would need to see a blend file with the mesh which is giving you problems. but is it possible that you set the offset on the solidify modifier in the wrong direction so that the normals are facing inwards? You can share the file via https://blend-exchange.com/ following the instructions.

Comment: maybe your normals are pointing the wrong direction? Try Alt N > Flip

Comment: looks like the file appeared. please delete your comment.

Comment: It looks like your blend file is the newer version that works, so we won't be able to guess.

Comment: Aren't we using same version? I mean.... what should I do about that?